# Load doctrine's entityManager with a specific environment

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Inside a test suite, I load doctrine's entity manager via container:

```
$this->manager = $this->container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
```

But this load entity manager for test environment. I want to save new records inside dev environment. I suppose the solution is to load entityManager with dev environment. But how?

Comment: could you explain what does it mean "Save new record inside dev environment"? Do you want save object to another db (not production)?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify your doctrine [configuration for Test environment](http://symfony.com/doc/current/testing.html#testing-configuration) inside `config_test.yml` file:

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver: pdo_mysql
        host: '%database_test_host%'
        port: '%database_test_port%'
        dbname: '%database_test_name%'
        user: '%database_test_user%'
        password: '%database_test_password%'
        charset: UTF8
```